get user-details from rest-auth/user
I want to get the details of the logged in user...
it's working on localhost, but not on remote
other paths e.g rest-auth/login/ etc are all working on remote except rest-auth/user
it keeps returning Server error(500)
my url pattern
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('dj_rest_auth.urls')),
]

config in setting
REST_AUTH = {
    'USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER': 'accounts.serializers.UserDetailsSerializer',
}

REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ]
}

i don't know what's wrong

Have you tried checking the logs?

Yes, nothing in the logs
